# How to get owner address from token account address

Tags: solana-web3js

I can't find the way to get owner address from token account address.
Please have a look at https://solscan.io/account/H289e6NPwxtUJws7YJrQnfgi8gYgHnnDi7Ur9FVBCr9Y

H289e6NPwxtUJws7YJrQnfgi8gYgHnnDi7Ur9FVBCr9Y is a token account address.
As you can see at solscan.io page, it's owner is HEGfxcbHPdkpxZJyqPaGevaAkCGfuaB1mHF1cUv2bTGe

How can I get the owner address by using solana/web3.js?